# How to enable Java object to access Spring property value?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

In one of my Spring xml property files, I have the following bean:

```
<bean class="com.project.TimerBean">
    <property name="delay" value="30000" />
    <property name="interval" value="60000" />
    <property name="invokeThis" value="com.project.TargetClass" />
    <property name="receiver" value="XYZ" />
</bean>
```

Essentially, `TimerBean` is used to invoke `TargetClass` within the specified values. There are several other instances of `TimerBean` declared in this property file.

Now I need `TargetClass` to access the value of `interval`. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT #1: To clarify my situation, `TimerBean` essentially creates an object of type `TargetClass`, some code inside `TargetClass` runs and then this object is used later in the execution. It's hard to be specific mainly because I'm lumping all the different beans into this `TargetClass` category, and each of them does different things. The only thing they have in common is this initialization in the property file.

Comment: Where is your target bean? Dont you have getter exposed in your TimerBean?

Comment: My guess is that TargetClass is not declared as a bean and I also believe that what you mean by "invoking" the target class is that you are invoking a static method in that class. Is this right?

Comment: Clarified the question, hopefully - @AndreiBalici

Comment: provided you with an answer that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.
Why don't you use Java's reflection to achieve your task?

If you know the fully qualified class name, you can instantiate an object like this:

```
Object instance = Class.forName("com.project.TargetClass").newInstance();
```

If the code that needs to be ran is in the constructor, you have achieved your goal.

If you need, however, to run a specific method of that instance:

```
Method method = instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methodName");
method.invoke(instance);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: don't forget to thumb up the answer as well :). thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this within a Spring Component:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

  @Autowired
  com.project.TimerBean timerBean;

  public void myFunc() {
      System.out.println(timerBean.getInterval());
  }
  ...
}
```